# check if 2 lists aren't the same print empty list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have tried to write an if/else statement check if the 2 lists I'm working with don't share any values. If they don't, I want to return an empty list. I can't work out how. Whenever I add in the statement if messes up my code to print inside the function and prints it the about of times a list item was entered or says invalid syntax.

The program is supposed to compare 2 lists, only print out the numbers they share in the list, only print single numbers if they repeat. If an empty string is entered, exit the program. If the lists don't share numbers print an empty list e.g Output: []
This is what I have so far. Should I also be using a return statement instead of print?

```
def mylist(list1,list2):
    same_num = []
    for i in list1:
        if i in list2:
            same_num.append(i) #put matching numbers into a list
            output = set(same_num) #convert to a set where no 2 thing will be the same
            output_list = list(output) #convert back to list for output
            print("Output: ", *output_list)
        else:
            print("Output: ", same_num)

ui1 = input('List 1: ')

if ui1 == "":
    print(" ")
else:
    ui2 = input('List 2: ')
    list1 = list(ui1)
    list2 = list(ui2)
    mylist(list1, list2)
```

Comment: What do you return if they're equal?

Comment: Why don't you just print 'all matching items in the lists'  which will be an empty list if there are none?

Comment: You don't need a loop. Start with something like: `[element for element in set(list1) if element in set(list2)]`. This returns the intersection of the two lists, with no repeated common values.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq if they're equal it doesn't matter, just print out the matching numbers :)

Comment: @JeffUK I'll try that, I think I'm over complicating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out already, you want to use a set for doing that. Sets keep only the unique elements and implement more efficient algorithms to check for intersection. In your case:

```py
def mylist(list1,list2):
    res = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
    print("Output: ", *res)
    return
```

Comment: Thank you! if I wanted to add a condition to check whether user input 1 is empty I just want to exit the program. If user input 1 contains numbers I want to continue through the program how can I get this if/else to work? its throwing back global variable errors:                                                                                          
`ui1 = input('List 1: ')
if ui1 == "":
     print(" ")
elif ui1 > "":
    ui2 = input('List 2: ')

list1 = list(ui1)
list2 = list(ui2)

print("output:",common(list1, list2))`

Comment: Make sure that the function you are calling has the same name as the one you defined. In my answer, I kept the original name `mylist`; in your comment you call `common` instead, that was the name proposed in a different answer.

Comment: Also, the string comparisons are unorthodox. An empty string is pythonically checked with `if not ui1` and not with `if ui1 == ""`; and you don't need `elif ui1 > ""`, a simple `else` is fine. The > comparison between strings check their alphabetical ordering. In this case, all strings are alphabetically after the empty string (I believe...) but it's not an intuitive nor safe way to check for an empty string.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, any ideas why it's still throwing an error that ui2 is not defined? I tried putting a variable at the top that ui2 = 0 but still didn't work.                   `ui1 = input('List 1: ')
if not ui1:
     print(" ")
else:
    ui2 = input('List 2: ')

list1 = list(ui1)
list2 = list(ui2)
`

Comment: I sorted it! my indenting was off, thanks for all your help :)

Comment: I'm happy to be of help. I see that you're a new contributor. The way StackOverflow works is that, if the answers you have received have been useful to you, you should upvote them and accept one. (I think that all three are good so they all probably deserve an upvote ;) )

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this:

```
def common(xs, ys):
    return list(set(xs).intersection(set(ys)))

xs = [...]
ys = [...]
print(common(xs, ys))
```

Comment: Maybe read the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- If you want to exit when the input is empty, you need a loop for when it is not.
- As `input` returns a string, calling `list()` on it will produce a list with separate characters. You don't want to separate '19 25' into ['1', '9', ' ', '2', '5'], so first split into words, then map those words to numbers.
- To get unique values (removing duplicates), use a `set`. To get values which are common in both lists, use the `intersection` method on the set.

Here is how it could look:

```
ui1 = input('List 1: (enter to quit)').split()
while ui1:
    ui2 = input('List 2: ').split()
    list1 = list(map(int, ui1))
    list2 = list(map(int, ui2))
    result = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
    print(result)
    
    # Again: ...
    ui1 = input('List 1: ').split()
```